# How do you add an alias to Swift TabularData Dataframe?

Tags: swift, dataframe, swiftui

Im trying to add aliases for columns in a data frame.  But the function does not seem to do anything.

```
DF.addAlias("None", forColumn: col.name)
print(DF.columnNames(forAlias: "None"))
```

This never prints anything. Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

To change the name of the column in a DataFrame:

```
var datiCSV: DataFrame {
    var collection = try! DataFrame(contentsOfCSVFile: url)
    collection.renameColumn("model_variable_code", to: "Sensore")
    return collection
}
```

For me work fine.